# How to cancel z-index at lower screen resolution?

Tags: media-queries, css-position, z-index

I'm not sure whether I should remove positioning or juste set z-index to auto.

```css
#partners{
width:100%;
height:400px;
padding-top:5%;
padding-bottom:5%;
margin:0 auto;
text-align: center; 
background-color:white;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
overflow: hidden;
    
}
#partners img{
display: inline-block;
width:24%;
}
 
#partners img:nth-child(2){
position: absolute;
z-index: 4;
left: 5%;
-ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(5deg);
}
#partners img:nth-child(3){
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
left: 25%;
-ms-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
#partners img:nth-child(4){
position: absolute;
z-index: 5;
right: 5%;
-ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(5deg);
}
#partners img:nth-child(5){
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
right: 27%;
-ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(5deg);
}


@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  
        
        #partners{
            z-index:0;
            position:static; 
        }
        #partners img{
            display: block;
            width:60%;
            z-index:0;
            position:static;
        }
        
        
 }
```

```html
<div id="partners">
    <h1>Partners, best friends</h1>
    <img src="img/personna1.jpg" alt=""   />
    <img src="img/personna2.jpg" alt=""   />
    <img src="img/personna3.jpg" alt=""   />
    <img src="img/personna4.jpg" alt=""   />
      </div>
```

I set z-index to some images, but when I'm on smaller resolutions, I would like to remove it. I can't figgure what's wrong, help, please....

Comment: Impossible for us to say given you haven't shown your attempt that didn't work. We can't help you with code we can't see.

Comment: do you use absolute position for this element? if you could share you code with use, we can simply answer it easier.

Comment: Yep, I added my code.

Comment: Yes, `z-index:0` is not the same as the default `z-index:auto`. So if you want to "cancel" it, use `auto`. Or, indeed, reset the `position` to `static`, which also switches z-indexing off. However, in your code snippet the images aren't visible, so we can't see what happens, nor what you want to happen instead.

Comment: Thanks, @MrLister, static positioning worked after I targeted the the img:nth-child as well.